# Powershell Scripting - How to use multiple columns\data sources for a powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell

Beginner scripter here.
I am trying to create a script using Add-AzureADApplicationOwner using a csv file with two columns. Then export the new values showing the name of the application with the new owners.

Please note that this is not to update the entire directory but only those applications without an owner.

Column A contains the new owners.
Column B contains the application IDs.

I am unable to do figure out how to do a loop that will assign column A Values to their column B values counterparts. I am also unable to figure out how to export the values with the actual name of the application instead of the object id.

Hoping to get some help! Thanks!

```
$AppId = Import-csv "C:\Users\crondon\Documents\Azure Tasks\azureapps.csv"

foreach ($assign in $appid)
{
   Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $assign.application -RefObjectId $assign.owner
   Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $assign.application | select objectid, displayname | Export-csv "C:\Users\crondon\Documents\Azure Tasks\new-azureowner.csv" -append
}
```

Comment: Does the CSV file have a header row with the column names `owner` and `application`?

Comment: Hello Mathias yes it does

Comment: Alright, so what's the problem? What happens when you run the code?

Comment: Hello Mathias. Don't know what I did wrong the first time but it looks like the code is working as intended. I am still stuck on exporting the list of new owners along with the application display name though. Can you please assist with that? Currently this gives me the display name of the owner and the owner objectid. I want the export to show the current owner and the name of the application:  Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $assign.application | select objectid, displayname | Export-csv "C:\Users\crondon\Documents\Azure Tasks\new-azureowner.csv" -append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am unable to do figure out how to do a loop that will assign column A Values to their column B values counterparts. I am also unable to figure out how to export the values with the actual name of the application instead of the object id.

To export the list of new owners along with the display name of the application and export the data to Excel, you can use the PowerShell script below

```
    $AppId = Import-Cs "C:\Venkat\Venkat\Apps\Apps.csv"
    foreach ($assign in $AppId) {
        $application = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $assign.application_ID
        #$owner = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $assign.owner_ID
    
        $existingOwners = Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $assign.application_ID
    
        if ($existingOwners.ObjectId -contains $owner.ObjectId) {
            Write-Host "Owner '$($owner.DisplayName)' is already added to the application '$($application.DisplayName)'. Skipping..."
            continue
        }
    
        Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $assign.application_ID -RefObjectId $assign.owner_ID
    
        $appowner = Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $assign.application_ID
    
        $output = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ApplicationName  = $application.DisplayName
            AppId            = $application.ObjectId
            UserObjId        = $appowner.ObjectId
            OwnerDisplayName = $appowner.DisplayName
            OwnerUPNName     = $appowner.UserPrincipalName
        }
    
        $output | Export-Csv "C:\Venkat\Venkat\Apps\azureowner.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
```

Once the above script is run and users are added to the application owners, retrieve the details from the application and export them to Excel.

[image]